# Observing a relationship in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I have a model with a relationship:

```
Whistlr.Organization = DS.Model.extend
  upload: DS.belongsTo('upload')
```

In the controller, I want to observe this relationship for changes:

```
Whistlr.OrganizationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend

  image: (->
    alert "The upload has changed!"
  ).property('upload')
```

But this doesn't trigger when I set the upload:

```
@set('upload', upload)
```

Can we observe relationships the same way we observe other properties? If not, is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `property` you're telling Ember that `image` is just something you want to display.  Ember expect the method to return a value, that is based on `'upload'`.  Ember will only call that method if you have previously displayed `image` in a template somewhere.  You probably want to use `observes` instead of `property`.  `observes` tells Ember that your app needs to take action any time that the `upload` value changes regardless of whether or not `image` has been displayed in a template.

```
  image: (->
    alert "The upload has changed!"
  ).observes('upload')
```

Here's some guidance in the Ember docs about how to decide which one to use: http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/what-do-i-use-when/

Comment: Thanks, Jeremy. Turns out that this snippet of code works (even with `property` instead of `observes`). The real problem was lying deeper in the code, which you helped me with over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19149404/setting-a-belongsto-relationship-on-a-dirty-object-in-ember-js/19189137?noredirect=1#19189137). Thanks again on both counts!