# Setting a belongsTo Relationship on a Dirty Object in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I'm using Ember.js 1.0 and Ember-Data 1.0.0beta2. I have a couple of related models:

```
Whistlr.Upload = DS.Model.extend
  organizations: DS.hasMany('organization')

Whistlr.Organization = DS.Model.extend
  upload: DS.belongsTo('upload')
```

The user creates the Upload within the Organization form via Jquery File Upload. In the success callback, I set the relationship like so:

```
upload = @get('parentView').get('controller').store.createRecord('upload', response.upload)
@get('parentView').get('controller').set('upload', upload)
```

Unfortunately, it's getting set to `null`. Is this because I'm trying to set the relationship while both the Organization and Upload instances are dirty?

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the upload on the controller instead of on a model.  You probably want to do :

```
@get('parentView').get('controller.model').set('upload', upload)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm getting an error message that `@get('parentView').get('controller.model')` is undefined. Perhaps the controller isn't associated with a model? I believe it's the OrganizationNewController, but perhaps in all the jumping around, it's landed on something else. How could I get the name of the controller that's been called?

Comment: If you just log the controller to the console you should be able to tell what it is : `console.log(@get('parentView').get('controller'));`

Comment: It appears that the model is null, but I'm still unsure which controller I'm working with. In the inspector, I can't find a name anywhere. (There's an immense tree of variables, and I have idea where to look.) The route is right, however: `organizations.new`. As a last resort, perhaps I could place a function in the route that handles this functionality?

Comment: Actually, I think I just found the name: `generated application controller`. Clearly not what I was looking for. I think I've seen this issue before. I'll look into again.

Comment: You may be getting the application controller because you're going through the 'parentView'.  What happens if you just do `@get('controller')`?

Comment: `undefined` again. I'm calling `parentView` here because the view this function takes place in is a reusable component (the `FileUploadView`), as opposed to the main `OrganizationsNewView`. I've just inserted it within the `OrganizationsNew` template. It looks like `parentView` isn't the right way to find `OrganizationsNewView` relative to this view, however.

Comment: Finally got this working. Turns out that my original code was fine, `@get('parentView').get('controller').set('upload', upload)`. However, because I hadn't instantiated a view for this form, `parentView` was a generated view rather than a view associated with the `OrganizationNewController`. I simply instantiated an empty view and everything started working: `Whistlr.OrganizationsNewView = Em.View.extend()`. Thanks for your help with this, especially in terms of debugging tips. I couldn't have figured this out without them.

Comment: Nice.  I'm glad you got it figured out.